# Добавить название кастомной таблицы в $wpdb

Tags: wordpress, hook

Уважаемые, коллеги, поделитесь опытом.

Могу ли я в своем плагине добавить в `$wpdb` название своей таблицы, чтобы потом обращаться к этой таблице `$wpdb->mihdan_statistics`, например так:

```
function mihdan_init() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->mihdan_statistics = $wpdb->prefix . 'mihdan_statistics';
}
add_action( 'init', 'mihdan_init' );
```

Насколько это правильно, не будет ли проблем в будущем? Или есть другой способ?

Comment: Можешь конечно. Никто не запрещает... Только у меня один вопрос, а этот код который ты предоставил, работает?? И на сколько корректно?

Comment: Работает корректно, использовал уже в нескольких плагинах. Была маза добавить свою таблицу в `$wpdb->tables[] = 'table'`, но судя по коду, этот массив помечен приватным.